# how to get Dictionary<int , ClassA> from Regex.Split

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `classA` that has some public properties & overrides `TosString` method  to to concatenate strings in these properties. It also has a property that returns int key;

I am using

```
string str = value1 + value2 + value3;
```

each value has # separated properties of `classA`

```
string[] values = Regex.Split(str,'#');

foreach(classA value in values)
{
    dictionary.add(value.key, value);
}
```

This works fine

=====================================================================

For this scenario I want to use

`values.ToDictionary`

Can any one suggest how to use this?

Comment: How does your snippet work? values is an array of strings, but you are expecting to enumerate them as objects of type classA.

Comment: I think "& it is working fine" should be revisited. I suspect that doesn't compile.

Comment: I don't understand how you are iterating the objects in an array of string as items of type classA. This plainly does not work, despite your assurances otherwise.

Comment: Does that work? Can you even imply a cast from a string to a class?

Comment: hello sir i am using this code but now i want to optimize it (to use feaure provided by .Net framework)

Comment: @Umbrella Even if this snippet worked (and I'm pretty sure it does not) ToDictionary() isn't really an optimization. It's convenient and pretty, but ultimately it's just going to enumerate your enumerable, apply the key extraction function, and add the result to a new Dictionary. It might actually be slower because of the function calls! If you have code that works, I would stick with it.

Comment: hello @umbrella. The problem with answering your question is that the code you have posted is completely broken. Nobody can optimize broken code, because from the code you have posted, we can't even guess at how it's meant to work.

Comment: it has a public constructor that split properties in to string & concat them in a string format . now getting my point?

Comment: @Umbrella, you might as well ask if we are psychic. Voting to close. Consider reading Jon Skeet's blog post about how to write questions. This one is very poorly asked. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs to me that you might *really* want is to get the properties from a class and turn them into key-value pairs in a dictionary.

If that's what you're looking to do then Class -> String ->  Array -> Dictionary is taking the long way.

If that's the case maybe you want to try a more direct approach

Given a class like this

```
 class classA
    { 
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public string  website { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public int reputation { get; set; }

        private string somthingPrivate { get; set; }


    }
```

The following creates a dictionary variable named result.

```
classA test = new classA() { Name = "Jeff Atwood", website = "codinghorror.com/blog", location = "El Cerrito, CA", age = 40, reputation = 15653 };


var result = test.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(property => property.Name,
                                                    property => property.GetValue(test,null),
                                                     StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

foreach (var key in result.Keys)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", key, result[key]);
```

And outputs this

```
Name : Jeff Atwood
website : codinghorror.com/blog
location : El Cerrito, CA
age : 40
reputation : 15653
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something along the lines of:

```
Regex.Split(str,'#')
.Select(s => new ClassA(s))
.ToDictionary(value => value.Key);
```

This will take each string that gets returned from `Split`, convert it to a `ClassA` somehow (that part is missing from your question), and return a dictionary where the keys all come from the `ClassA` instances and the values are the instances themselves.

Comment: +1 I think this is what they want, as best I can tell, only thing I would do different is use `string.Split` instead of `Regex.Split`

Comment: @juharr: Yes, `string.Split` is better for this case, but if he ever needs to escape the delimiter (i.e. ignore `\#`), he will need a regex.